# Powershell RegEX Folder Tree

Tags: regex

Will someone please explain the differences in these two RegEx? (Between version 1 and version 2) The only difference I see in them is an extra `(.:\\.*?)` But if anyone can explain to me what this means it would be greatly appreciated!

**First Version**

```
$folders |?{$_ -match "^(.:\\.+?)(\\\d{2}-\d{2})(\\.*)$"}|%{$_ = "$($Matches[1])\$YY$($Matches[3])"; New-Item $_ -ItemType directory | Out-Null}

$Folders | ?{$_ -match "^(.:\\.*?)(\\\d{2}-\d{2})(\\.*)"}|%{$Matches[1]} | Select -Unique |?{$_}| %{
```

**Second Version**

```
$folders |?{$_ -match "^(.:\\.+?)(.:\\.+?)(\\\d{2}-\d{2})(\\.*)$"}|%{$_ = "$($Matches[1])\$YY$($Matches[3])"; New-Item $_ -ItemType directory | Out-Null}

$Folders | ?{$_ -match "^(.:\\.*?)(.:\\.+?)(\\\d{2}-\d{2})(\\.*)"}|%{$Matches[1]} | Select -Unique |?{$_}| %{
```

Answer (score 1):

**RegExp:** `(.:\\.*?)`

- `(` opens a numbered match group
- `.` matches every character - only one because there is no ?, +, *, or {...} after `.`
- `\\` matches a `\` character
- `.*` matches any character for any times (zero, one, ..., infinite)
- `?` tells `*` to be not greedy, so `.*` will match all chars until the next `\`
- `)` closes the match group

**Example:**

```
Input:
  `D:\Dept\CC\SDL\14-15\StaffAdministration\CFCA`  
RegExp:
  `^(.:\\.+?)(\\\d{2}-\d{2})(\\.*)$`
Result:
  $Matches[0] = "D:\Dept\CC\SDL\14-15\StaffAdministration\CFCA"
  $Matches[1] = "D:\Dept\CC\SDL"
  $Matches[2] = "\14-15"
  $Matches[3] = "\StaffAdministration\CFCA"
```

if `$YY` is `"xxx"` then `"$($Matches[1])\$YY$($Matches[3])"` evaluates to
`"D:\Dept\CC\SDL\xxx\StaffAdministration\CFCA"`

The second regexp version does not match, because there is no second `:` character.

*NOTE:*
There are easyier ways to replace `14-15` by another string.
See the `-replace` operator for more details.

**Appendix:**

- `a?` = a{0,1}
- `a+` = a{1,}
- `a*` = a{0,}
- `aa` = a{2}

Here is the .NET [Regular Expression Language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) reference.

Here is also the [RegExp reference](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) from Python. PowerShell/.NET uses nearly the same syntax.

Comment: why do they use it twice on the second one? doesn't the first do that same?

Comment: `(.:\\.+?)(.:\\.+?)` is equal to `(.:\\.+?){2}`. They used copy&paste instead of using an explicit count like `{2}`. It just matches `.:\\.+` two times.

Comment: what does it have to do with a folder structure?

Comment: Testing for `(.:\\.+?){2}` makes no sense in the context of windows folders. This expression is rather weak. The first `.` matches for a drive letter. Better solution: `[a-zA-Z]`, because only single letters are supported as drive names. testing for a second `:` makes no sense, because `:` is a special char/separator and can only appear once in a path.

Comment: It consumes at least one or every character until one character before the next `:`. NOTE: `$Matches[3]` should be `$Matches[4]`, because there is an additional group in the regexp, so `(\\.*)` has now the index 4.

Comment: *D:\Dept\CC\SDL\14-15\StaffAdministration\CFCA* So based on this I would use the regex and match[4]? but take out the second (.:\\.+?)

Comment: @ZaneZ I extended my answer for your example. Maybe you can describe your overall goal and I can try to find a better suitable regexp for your problem. Can you name any constrains? E.g. `14-15` is the only folder with numbers, or `14-15` is at folder-level 3 from root/device, ...

Comment: do you know powershell? maybe I can show you what I am trying to figure out

Comment: Yes, I'm a PS user :).

Comment: can I show you my script and see if u can help me can we chat?